# Copy all selected data in a table on Page

Tags: javascript, html

My code for the button select all data in a table display on the page. I want to make another button that will copy the selected values. Any ideas??below is my code:

```
        function selectElementContents(el) {
     var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
    range = document.createRange();
    sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    try {
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        sel.addRange(range);
    } catch (e) {
        range.selectNode(el);
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
      } else if (body.createTextRange) {
    range = body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(el);
    range.select();
     }
         }
     </script>
      <input type="button" value="select table" 
     onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('btnexport') 
      );"> 

        <table id="btnexport">

        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>rrr</td>
        </table>
```

Comment: you want to get all rows of table which were selected?

Comment: yes all the values that are selected in the table display

Comment: copy to clipboard?

Comment: yes copy to clipboard by pressing another button

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands

Comment: could you please tell did my answer help?

Comment: could you plz is your problem solved?

Comment: not at all it did not solve

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copy()
{
document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="copy()">copy</button>

        <table id="btnexport">

        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>rrr</td>
        </table>
```